# Carbon get interested week in two weeks range date

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

I'm trying to write an algorithm which calculate the week (saturday to saturday) of interest based on a range of date.
For example I have this range:

```
2018-01-04 to 2018-01-13
```

In this case I have two weeks of interest, it is: "week 1" From 01 to 07 of January and "week 2" From 08 to 14 of the same January.

In this case the algorithm will respond to me that the week of interest is the "Week 2" because the number of days in that week is higher than the number of days in the "week 1".

How can I do this in Carbon?

Comment: what's the question? did you tried anything? its just a idea.

Comment: The question is how i can do this in Carbon :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Assuming you have the start and end date as Carbon objects `$s` and `$e`
- make sure the difference is less than 14 days
- calculate the overlaps:

  - `$s->diffInDays($s->copy()->startOfWeek())` "offset" into first week
  - `$e->copy()->endOfWeek()->diffInDays($e)` "remainder" of last week
- if `$offset > $remainder` select `$e`; else select `$s`
- output `$selectedWeek->copy()->startOfWeek()` and `$selectedWeek->copy()->endOfWeek()`

Apparently, `startOfWeek()` and `endOfWeek()` alter the object; so make sure to `copy()` before using these methods!

Implementation:

```
$s = new Carbon\Carbon('2018-01-04');
$e = new Carbon\Carbon('2018-01-13');
$diff = $e->diffInDays($s);
if ($diff > 14) die("uh-oh!");
$offset = $s->diffInDays($s->copy()->startOfWeek());
$remainder = $e->copy()->endOfWeek()->diffInDays($e);
$selectedWeek = ($offset > $remainder ? $e : $s)->copy()->startOfWeek();
echo "selected week {$selectedWeek->weekOfYear} ({$selectedWeek} - {$selectedWeek->copy()->endOfWeek()})";
```

Output:

```
selected week 2 (2018-01-08 00:00:00 - 2018-01-14 23:59:59)
```

Comment: it works perfectly, but if i have a range for example of 30 days it breaks.
in this case i select the first week +1 week.
example:
from 2018-05-02 to 2018-05-31 they will return to me week 19 not 21

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do something like this. I haven't tested it but you can get some idea. Also I would like to point to the documentation https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

```
// Create dates
$date1 = Carbon::create(2018, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0);
$date2 = Carbon::create(2018, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0);

// Get The week numbers
$week_date_1 = $date1->weekOfYear; 
$week_date_2 = $date2->weekOfYear; 

// Count number of days for each week
$number_of_days_week_1 = $date1->diffInDays($date1->startOfWeek); 
$number_of_days_week_2 = $date2->diffInDays($date2->startOfWeek); 

// Highest number of days per week wins
if($number_of_days_week_1 > $number_of_days_week_2){
   return $week_date_1; 
} else {
   return $week_date_2; 
}
```

Comment: thank you, your solution works but in my case instead of "return $week_date_2; " i write "return $week_date_1+1; "